# How to include Hubspot script in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, analytics, hubspot

I need to use the Hubspot tracking code into a Chrome Extension but I have some problems related with the Chrome URI protocol because it uses chrome:// instead http(s)://

These are the steps I follow so far:

1. Replace the src to force https: https://js.hs-analytics.net/analytics/
2. Add the domain to the manifest.json

But when the script runs, it tries to download resources from a relative url which turns into chrome://track.hubspot.com and fails.

Does exist any way to modify this behaviour without having to download the file and modify it?

Answer (score -1):

To include a HubSpot script in a Chrome Extension, you can follow these steps:

1. Open your Chrome Extension's codebase in your preferred code editor.
2. Locate the file where you want to include the HubSpot script. This could be your background script, content script, or any other relevant file for your extension's functionality.
3. Obtain the HubSpot script code from your HubSpot account or HubSpot documentation. It typically looks like:

   javascript


   // Your HubSpot script code here
4. Copy the HubSpot script code.
5. Paste the copied HubSpot script code into the desired file of your Chrome Extension codebase.
6. Save the file.
7. Make sure to declare the necessary permissions in your Chrome Extension's manifest file (manifest.json). For HubSpot, you might need to include the following permission:

   ```
   json
   "permissions": [
     "https://api.hubspot.com/*"
   ]
   ```

   Adjust the URL as per your HubSpot API or tracking needs.
8. Now, you can access and utilize the HubSpot script in your Chrome Extension as per your requirements.

Remember to test your extension thoroughly to ensure the HubSpot script works seamlessly within the extension's environment.

Good luck with your Chrome Extension and the HubSpot integration! If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.